# Removing an element from an array which is an element of an object

Tags: php

I'm working on a filter system to filter out food items being displayed on a menu. Every document in the menu collection contains the name of the category (or course if you will) and an array of food items.

I've tried various solutions such as the following code which gets me closer to the desired output.

```
foreach($menu as $category){

   foreach($category["fooditems"] as $fooditem){

       if ($fooditem["vegetarian"] == false){
                 if (($key = array_search($fooditem, (array) $category["fooditems"])) !== false) 
                    unset($category["fooditems"][$key]);        
    }
  }
}
```

Before:

```
{
    "category" : "Starters",
    "fooditems" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "No meat",
            "vegetarian" : true,

        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Horse Meat",
            "vegetarian" : false,
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Some more meat",
            "vegetarian" : false,
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected after:

```
{
    "category" : "Starters",
    "fooditems" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "No meat",
            "vegetarian" : true,

        }
    ]
}
```

Actual after:

```
{
    "category" : "Starters",
    "fooditems" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "No meat",
            "vegetarian" : true,

        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Some more meat",
            "vegetarian" : false,
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is after it spots a non-vegetarian food item and unsets it, it stops looping. I have no idea why this occurs.

Thank you to anyone who answers :)

Comment: you have an extra bracket in your loop? Also, it's better to use `== false` instead of comparing a string IMO.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the extra bracket and also updated the code altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After decoding the JSON to an array with `true` you can filter and return only what is equal to `true`:

```
$menu['fooditems'] = array_filter($menu['fooditems'],
                                  function($v) {
                                      return $v['vegetarian'] === true;
                                  });
```

To use your loop, just track the key and `unset` using the full path to the array:

```
foreach($menu['fooditems'] as $key => $values) {
    if($values['vegetarian'] === false) {
        unset($menu['fooditems'][$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: To make that work you need to mod `$v['vegetarian'] === true;` to `$v['vegetarian'] === "true";`

Comment: Ditto the foreach version

Comment: Wrapped the first solution in a foreach loop (since I needed to loop it for every category) and it worked just fine. Thank you very much!

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Any reason why the foreach solution is better?

Comment: I didnt say the foreach was better !

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Haha sorry then my mistake :-)

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Why?  They are boolean not strings.

Comment: No they should be strings as JSON only supports string